# Generar token único en Php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Con tal de generar un token único para relacionar en SQL cierta información, después de revisar alguna documentación, veo las opciones para generar un token que sea único. Este token estará presente en dos tablas y en cada una de las dos tablas en varias filas. Veo dos opciones, para un token de 32 carácteres.

**Opción 1**

```
$ttime = microtime(true)*1000;
$token = $ttime . str_shuffle("ABCDEFGHIJKLNMOPQR");
```

**Opción 2**

```
$token = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));
```

Mi duda surge al leer que no es aconsejable utilizar la función microtime() para generar tokens únicos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Una alternativa seria usar `uniqueid()`, obtener un identificador único prefijado basado en la hora actual en microsegundos.

> **¡Precaución**! esta función no genera tokens criptográficamente seguros, de hecho, el valor devuelto, sin pasar ningún parámetro adicional, es ligeramente diferente del de microtime(). Si fuera necesario generar tokens criptográficamente seguros utilice openssl_random_pseudo_bytes().

**Ejemplo A:**

```
echo uniqid();
// Salida: 261b8fbcdc4ff0
```

[Manual: uniqid](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.uniqid.php)

Ahora si deseas usar `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` para generar tokens criptográficamente seguros, este genera una cadena de bytes pseudo-aleatoria, con el número de bytes determinado por el parámetro *length*.

**Ejemplo B:**

```
$x = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
echo $x;
// Salida: 6f19e8d4f5df8fae1e124941a48d980f (32 caracteres)
```

[Manual: openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php)

**Edit:**
Ahora que tengo un poco más de tiempo, te dejo otro ejemplo que tengo guardado hace tiempo de *SO*, que me gusta bastante.

Por ejemplo, si quieres encriptar un id y guardar este encriptado en la BD y posterior desencriptarlo para trabajar con este **ID**, podrías por ejemplo crear una función como el ejemplo.

**Ejemplo C:**

```
// Function encriptado|desencriptado
function encrypt_decrypt($action, $string) :string {
   $output = false;
   $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
   $secret_key = 'tu_clave_secreta';
   $secret_iv = 'salt_secreto';
   // hash
   $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);    
   // iv - encrypt method AES-256-CBC expects 16 bytes 
   $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);
   if ( $action == 'encrypt' ) {
      $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
          $output = base64_encode($output);
   } else if( $action == 'decrypt' ) {
      $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
   }
   return $output;
 }

 // Trabajamos con la función
 //
 // Encriptas id 5008   
 $encriptar = encrypt_decrypt('encrypt',5008);
 echo $encriptar . '<br>';

 // Desencriptas el id para verlo de manera original
 $decriptar = encrypt_decrypt('decrypt',$encriptar);
 echo $decriptar;

 // salidas:
 // bnR6UTRVTHAzYWd1dWEvWVdpMGo4QT09 (corresponde a 5008)
 // 5008
```

Answer (score 3):

Quizás estos te sirvan:

**EJEMPLO:**

```
<?php 
 
$token1 = mt_rand(3, 16).mt_rand(0,16); 
$token2 = substr(md5("ADBCKSJDF".time()."EFGHPOWJDKAW"),0, 16).mt_rand(5, 16);

?>
```

Espero haberte ayudado!

Answer (score 3):

yo uso este:

```
function token(){
    $r1 = bin2hex(random_bytes(10));
    $r2 = bin2hex(random_bytes(10));
    $r3 = bin2hex(random_bytes(10));
    $r4 = bin2hex(random_bytes(10));

    $token = $r1.'-'.$r2.'-'.$r3.'-'.$r4;

    return $token;
}

echo token();
```

No utilizo `microtime`, pero bueno, es una opcion.
Besis

Answer (score 2):

yo tengo uno personal en la cual la tengo en una función y puede genera la cantidad de caracteres segun el numero que mande, permite genera caracteres Mayúsculas y minúscula y con números

```
<?php

    public function Obtener_token($cantidadCaracteres)
    {
          
            $Caracteres = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
            $ca = strlen($Caracteres);
            $ca--;
            $Hash = '';
            for ($x = 1; $x <= $cantidadCaracteres; $x++) {
                $Posicao = rand(0, $ca);
                $Hash .= substr($Caracteres, $Posicao, 1);
            }
            return $Hash;
    }
```