# ¿Cómo encriptar la url en php usando MVC?

Tags: php, mvc, url, encriptación

Estoy trabajando con PHP modelo Vista Controlador y quiero encriptar la url de la siguiente manera: http://localhost/siginv/Herramienta/TGlzdGFySGVycmFtaWVudGEy
Donde `Herramienta` es mi controlador y lo que sigue sería mi función encriptada dentro del modelo.
¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

```
<?php 
$encrypt = 'ListarHerramienta';
$link = "http://localhost/siginv/Herramienta/". urlencode(base64_encode($encrypt));
?> 
<a href="<?=$link?>">Herramienta</a>
```

La función se llama `ListarHerramienta` la cual quiero encriptar para tenernar a la vista,
La encriptación de la url sale bien pero al dar click obtengo un error.

```
public function ListarHerramienta(){
            $data = 'ListarHerramienta';
            
            foreach($_GET as $key => $data){
                $data2 = $_GET[$key] = base64_decode(urldecode($data)); 
                if($data2 == $data) {
                    echo 'si';
                }
             }

            $this->vista('inventario/herramientas/ListarHerramienta');
        }
```

Agradezco ayuda, please.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! al darle click a que?

Comment: Fíjate en el *ejemplo C* de esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/503219/generar-token-%c3%banico-en-php/503268#503268 es una función que hace lo que deseas.